# Assigned the Droid Serif font to an HTML element but my Android phone still displaying Droid Sans?

Tags: android, css

I have this in my CSS:

```
.like-counter span, .entry-content h2 {
    color: #444;
    font-family: Bitstream Charter, "Droid Serif", Gerogia, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

In my computer, I see a serif font. If I remove the first one, then I see the Droid Serif font. I thought this font was a default font in Android devices.

But when I open the site on my Android phone. I'm still seeing Droid Sans.

What could be causing this?

EDIT:

I discovered that the problem only happens when I display the page in Android's default browser. In Firefox, I can see the Droid Serif font (strange).

Comment: Does the Android browser allow you to use custom fonts?

Comment: @Blender How can I check that?

Comment: Open this up in the Android browser: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html

Comment: @Blender most serif fonts in that site you gave me are displaying the Droid Serif font. I don't understand why is not working on my site: http://www.taiwantalk.org/.

Comment: Move `serif` before `Droid Serif`. Or to the very front. You might need a conditional stylesheet for Android (no idea why this isn't working for you).

Comment: @Blender Hey that worked, strange, what could be the reason (please post the answer so I can tick it).

Comment: Done. Does this work in desktop browsers? I would think it would break on desktop browsers now.

Comment: @Blender No, it doesn't why would it break?

Comment: Because the order of the fonts matters (first one is the default. If the first one isn't installed, then the second one is tried, etc.). I use the Droid fonts in my browser, so the `serif` font for me is `Droid Serif`. But on other browsers, it might be something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of guessing the default fonts, you can just use the generic `serif` font:

```
font-family: serif;
```

`serif` will be the browser's default serif font.

Comment: That sort-of helps, but only as regards to getting a serif font on Android. It pretty much defeats the idea of having a list of specific fonts, since on *any* browser, the generic name `serif` has a meaning, and you will *always* get each browser’s default serif font. Just as you would with mere `font-family: serif`.

Answer (score 2):

On older Android systems (until a version that I'm not aware of) the browser instead of checking the full list of possible fonts, it checks the very first entry of the font family, and if it is known to the browser, what to substitute it with, then it will use that, otherwise it will throw away the whole list.
This is notable, if you just use Times for example, it will use Droid Serif, but if you add some fancy font before it, it will use Droid Sans, regardles of the rest.

Obviously it will work, if you put the “serif” in first place, but then all the browser use the default serif font, instead of whatever you want. Because of the simplicity of the font selection on older Android, you can add a `"serif"` family to the first place, which will be interpreted as Droid Serif on the old Android, but other browsers will look (and hopefully fail) for a font named “serif”.

Also—interestingly—none of the Droid fonts are known to those Android browser.

Comment: So this workaround would mean using e.g. `font-family: "serif", Bitstream Charter, Georgia, serif;`, where the quotes in `"serif"` are essential, making it a specific font name, presumable recognized only by the old Android browser, which on the other hand does not process `font-family` correctly (at least up to version 2.3.5). This way, old Androids will use their sans serif font (which apparently cannot be called in CSS with any real name), whereas other browsers ignore `"serif"` at the start.

Comment: Old Android will use the *serif* font, but yes, that's the case. I also find out, that on some Linux distros, there is a font installed named san-serif, so this trick far from perfect. - That is why I added "hopefully fails."