# CSS: I ask for serif, Android gives me sans-serif

Tags: android, css, fonts

I've got the following font stack on my website:

```
font-family: Skolar, Tisa, "Chaparral Pro", Merriweather, Georgia, serif;
```

But for some reason Android (version 2.3.5, native browser) keeps giving me a sans-serif font. However, it works if I remove every font except `Georgia` and `serif`.

This is getting really frustrating. Any ideas?

Comment: While browser should've support like that, tried adding quotes to all names? I know is only needed for names with spaces, but who knows. Other than that, does you know if the browser HAVE those fonts? (or if you are making the `@font-face` correctly?)

Comment: Strangely, the problem can be reproduced with a minimal document and even with the declaration simplified to `font-family: foobar, Georgia`. An unknown font seems to make Android use its default sans-serif font.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL These are no custom fonts. And the quotes made no difference. :-)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela So you encountered the same problem? Then I've overestimated Google when it comes to CSS basics. Is there any known workaround?

Comment: Yes, when testing now. The Android default browser really gets things all wrong. Sorry, I can’t see a workaround, but I found an old question and I think this is a duplicate of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigned the Droid Serif font to an HTML element but my Android phone still displaying Droid Sans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829150/assigned-the-droid-serif-font-to-an-html-element-but-my-android-phone-still-disp)

Comment: The old question actually has an answer with a working workaround: use `"serif"` (with quotes!) at the start of the font list.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, my hero! If you put that as an answer I'll accept it. :-)

Comment: give it sans-serif it will give you serif :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered earlier, in question: [Assigned the Droid Serif font to an HTML element but my Android phone still displaying Droid Sans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829150/assigned-the-droid-serif-font-to-an-html-element-but-my-android-phone-still-disp)

You should start your font-face line from "serif":

```
font-face: "serif";
```